# harvard cs109 homework0 switch_guesses

Tags: python

```
def switch_guess(guesses, goatdoors):

    result = np.zeros(guesses.size)
    switch = {(0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 1, (1, 0): 2, (1, 2): 1, (2, 0): 1, (2, 1): 0}
    for i in [0, 1, 2]:
        for j in [0, 1, 2]:
            mask = (guesses == i) & (goatdoors == j)
            if not mask.any():
                continue
            result = np.where(mask, np.ones_like(result) * switch[(i, j)], result)
    return result
```

don't quite understand how this works, can anybody helps explain it?
thanks!

> hints:
>
> Returns   The new door after switching. Should be different from both
>   guesses and goatdoors
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> >>> print switch_guess(np.array([0, 1, 2]), np.array([1, 2, 1]))
> >>> array([2, 0, 0])
> """
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You might have some trouble understanding this example due to a mistake in the 4th entry of the switch dictionary. It should be as follows:

```
switch = {(0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 1, (1, 0): 2, (1, 2): 0, (2, 0): 1, (2, 1): 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added some comments throughout the source, which explain my understanding of the code. It does look a lot like the Monty Hall experiment, so I'm guessing the idea is that the function basically says:

> Given that you guessed `guesses[i]` and there is a goat behind `goatdoors[i]`, you should switch and pick door `results[i]`.

It also seems a slightly convoluted way to go about this problem, if I understood it correctly.

```
def switch_guess(guesses, goatdoors):
    # Initialise result to an array of zeros, the same size as the guesses array
    result = np.zeros(guesses.size)
    # Create a dictionary to be used later in determining the values of result.
    switch = {(0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 1, (1, 0): 2, (1, 2): 1, (2, 0): 1, (2, 1): 0}
    for i in [0, 1, 2]:
        for j in [0, 1, 2]:
            # Create a mask, which is True when the corresponding elements of 
            # guesses and goatdoors are both equal to i and j, respectively.
            mask = (guesses == i) & (goatdoors == j)
            # If no elements of mask are true, go to the next loop iteration (of 
            # the j loop).
            if not mask.any():
                continue
            # For each element of result, if the corresponding element of mask
            # is True, set the element of result to 1 * switch[(i, j)], otherwise
            # leave it unchanged.
            result = np.where(mask, np.ones_like(result) * switch[(i, j)], result)
    return result
```